# SVN checkout automation batch

Tags: batch-file, svn, svn-checkout

I have come up with this

```
echo.
echo. [ SVN Updater ]
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set SOURCE=E:\Svncheckout\
set SVN=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
set SVN_REPO_URL=https://SVNSERVERIP/svn/
set projects=project1/branches/hello1 project2/branches/hello2
set checkoutdir=project1 project2
echo.
SET PROJCOUNT=0
(for %%i in (%projects%) do (
  echo. Checking out %SVN_REPO_URL%%%i from SVN...
  "%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:checkout /path:"%SOURCE%%checkoutdir[0]%" /url:"%SVN_REPO_URL%%%i" /closeonend:2
   PROJCOUNT+=1;  
)
)
echo.
echo. Operation complete.
```

I would like to iterate the `checkoutdir` list array with each directory name. I'm stuck here. I'm newbie to batch programming. Kindly help

Method 2 :

```
echo.
echo. [ SVN Updater ]
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set SOURCE=E:\Svncheckout\21MAY2016\
set SVN=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
set SVN_REPO_URL=https://192.168.1.35:8443/svn/
set projects=JPO/JPOMobile/branches/2016-05-18 JPO/JPOWEB/branches/20160518
set checkoutdir=JPOMobile JPOWEB
set /A CHECKOUTCOUNT=1
set /A PROJCOUNT=0
(for %%i in (%projects%) do (
         SET /A "PROJCOUNT+=1"
    (for %%a in (%checkoutdir%) do (
        IF ("%PROJCOUNT%"=="%CHECKOUTCOUNT%") (
            echo. Checking out %SVN_REPO_URL%%%i from SVN...
            "%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:checkout /path:"%SOURCE%%%a" /url:"%SVN_REPO_URL%%%i" /closeonend:2
            SET /A "CHECKOUTCOUNT+=1"
        )    

    ))
))
echo.
echo. Operation complete.
```

In the second method, it errors, set /A PROJCOUNT=0 in unexpected at this time.I think there is some problem in the `for` loop

Comment: I can see that you know `for %%i in (%projects%) do ( rem some code here …)` approach. Apply it as follows: `for %%G in (%checkoutdir%) do ( rem %%i loop here)` but use `%%~G` instead of `%checkoutdir[0]%`. There is nothing like _list array_ in batch scripting: there are only _strings_ (or _numbers_ somewhen).

Comment: @JosefZ I have updated another try. Can you help me?

Comment: Why to use Tortoise GUI ? For those interested, you could also directly use SVN command line : "%SVN%\svn.exe" checkout "%SVN_REPO_URL%%~1" "%SOURCE%%%D"

Comment: Yeah, good point. I think, we have to allow use to choose the directory before checking out the repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution for this task:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo. [ SVN Updater ]
set "SOURCE=E:\Svncheckout\21MAY2016\"
set "SVN=%ProgramFiles%\TortoiseSVN\bin"
set "SVN_REPO_URL=https://192.168.1.35:8443/svn/"
set "projects=JPO/JPOMobile/branches/2016-05-18 JPO/JPOWEB/branches/20160518"
set "checkoutdir=JPOMobile JPOWEB"
set "ProjectCount=0"
for %%P in (%projects%) do call :CheckOut "%%P"
echo.
echo. Operation complete.

rem Exit batch processing to avoid a fall through to subroutine.
exit /B

:CheckOut
set /A ProjectCount+=1
for /F "tokens=%ProjectCount%" %%D in ("%checkoutdir%") do (
    echo. Checking out %SVN_REPO_URL%%~1 from SVN...
    "%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:checkout /path:"%SOURCE%%%D" /url:"%SVN_REPO_URL%%~1" /closeonend:2
)
rem Exit this subroutine. It is also possible to use GOTO :EOF
exit /B
```

The first loop processes each project defined in environment variable `projects` separated by a space. For each project the subroutine `CheckOut` is called with the current project path as argument.

The subroutine `CheckOut` first increments the project count variable which is the checkout directory string index with first string having index number 1.

The second loop in this subroutine interprets the list of directories in environment variable `checkoutdir` now as a string instead of a list of strings because of using parameter `/F` of **FOR** and enclosing the value of the environment variable in double quotes.

To get the Nth checkout directory from the string with the checkout directories separated by spaces, the `tokens=x` syntax is used whereby `x` is the current value of project count variable.

The checkout is done with the Nth checkout directory and the current project referenced with `%~1` as being passed to the subroutine as first argument.

For details on using subroutines and referencing parameters run in a command prompt window `call /?` and read all output help pages.

A subroutine as used here is like having another batch file embedded in current batch file.

**NOTE:** There is a limit of 31 tokens. `ProjectCount` should therefore not exceed the value 31.

Answer (score 1):

**1st**: wrong [IF syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html): remove next **harmful parentheses**

```
    IF ("%PROJCOUNT%"=="%CHECKOUTCOUNT%") (
rem    ^                                ^
```

**2nd**: [variables within parenthesized command blocks](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution
>   time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the
>   [SETLOCAL command](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html). When delayed expansion is in effect variables
>   can be referenced using `!variable_name!` (in addition to the normal
>   `%variable_name%`).

You need to **apply** *Delayed Expansion* **where necessary** as declaring it does not suffice.

**3rd** (cosmetic bug): remove **unnecessary parentheses**.

Updated code: note that `TortoiseProc.exe` command is merely ECHOed for debugging purposes.

```
echo off
echo.
echo. [ SVN Updater ]
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set SOURCE=E:\Svncheckout\21MAY2016\
set SVN=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
set SVN_REPO_URL=https://192.168.1.35:8443/svn/
set projects=JPO/JPOMobile/branches/2016-05-18 JPO/JPOWEB/branches/20160518
set checkoutdir=JPOMobile JPOWEB
set /A CHECKOUTCOUNT=1
set /A PROJCOUNT=0
for %%i in (%projects%) do (
         SET /A "PROJCOUNT+=1"
    for %%a in (%checkoutdir%) do (
        rem wrong IF ("%PROJCOUNT%"=="%CHECKOUTCOUNT%") (
        rem right IF  "!PROJCOUNT!"=="!CHECKOUTCOUNT!"  (
        rem or    IF !PROJCOUNT!  EQU !CHECKOUTCOUNT!   (
        IF !PROJCOUNT! EQU !CHECKOUTCOUNT! (
            echo. Checking out %SVN_REPO_URL%%%i from SVN...
            ECHO "%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:checkout /path:"%SOURCE%%%a" /url:"%SVN_REPO_URL%%%i" /closeonend:2
            SET /A "CHECKOUTCOUNT+=1"
        )    

    )
)
echo.
echo. Operation complete. 
echo. debug     PROJCOUNT=%PROJCOUNT%
echo.       CHECKOUTCOUNT=%CHECKOUTCOUNT%
```